# Spring confiuration reading incorrect value from the properties file while creating JDBC connection

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring Configuration bean which looks like this

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db/jdbc2.properties")
public class DbConfig {

    @Value("${driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
            Class<? extends Driver> driver = (Class<? extends Driver>) Class.forName(driverClassName);
            dataSource.setDriverClass(driver);
            dataSource.setUrl(url);
            dataSource.setUsername(username);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            return dataSource;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

The jdbc2.properties file looks like this

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musicdb?useSSL=true
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musicdb
username=prospring6
password=prospring6
```

However, when I run try to get JDBC connection, I get the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Delta'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Even though, username field is set prospring6 in the properties file, the configuration is reading it as Delta, which is my system's username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows then might be this is the issue.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

(See the platform dependency issue section)

Changed the property key from username to db.username (it should be anything but not only username)... might be it will starts working.